# Alarmmanager display toast at intervals

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Hello I'm new to Java and android, I'm trying to use alarmmanager with a chronometer to display a toast every 10 seconds after the startButton is pressed. Nothing is happening after 10 seconds and I'm not sure why.

Can you look at my code and help me to identify and resolve the problems?

Thankyou.

variables - journeycount = chronometer, pendingIntent mAlarmSender

Main Class - SafeDrive3Activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

            journeycount = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.journeycount);
            // Watch for button clicks.
            startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
            startButton.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);

            resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
            resetButton.setOnClickListener(mResetListener);

        }

View.OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

      int stoppedMilliseconds = 0;

      String chronoText = journeycount.getText().toString();
      String array[] = chronoText.split(":");

      if (array.length == 2) {
        stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 1000
            + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 1000;
      } else if (array.length == 3) {
        stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 60 * 1000 
            + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 60 * 1000
            + Integer.parseInt(array[2]) * 1000;
      }

      journeycount.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - stoppedMilliseconds);
      journeycount.start();
      startButton.setText("Driving..."); // changes button text value to 'Driving...'
      startButton.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);

      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
      // add 10 seconds to calendar object
      cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
      mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SafeDrive3Activity.this,
              0, new Intent(SafeDrive3Activity.this, MyTimeReceiver.class), 0);

      // Schedule the alarm!
      AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
      am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                      cal.getTimeInMillis(), mAlarmSender);

    }
    };

        View.OnClickListener mResetListener = new OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  Button startButton;
                  startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
                  startButton.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);
                  journeycount.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

                  startButton.setText("Start Driving");
                  journeycount.setText("00:00");
                  journeycount.stop();

                  AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
                  am.cancel(mAlarmSender);


              }
        };


              };
```

Second Class:

```
public class MyTimeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 

{
    @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Toast.makeText(context, "HOUR NOTIFICATION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
         }
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.Safe"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".SafeDrive3Activity" >
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"  />
        </intent-filter>
    <receiver android:name="MyTimeReceiver"></receiver>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Still struggling to get the toast to display, I think its just a small problem with the code, any ideas :( ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider a different approach in this scenario. Why not using a Timer that just launch toasts messages?

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(SafeDrive3Activity.this, "Whatever", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}, 0, 10000);
```

Comment: How to disable the timer task in onDestroy method of service class?

Answer (score 0):

use below code set alarm manager

```
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                  SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),mAlarmSender);
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I've changed it to above code but still no toast text is coming up on 10 seconds. I'm getting the error below when intent is started on the emulator, is that anything to do with it?

SafeDrive3] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Comment: clean the project and run again

Comment: Done. I don't think the above changes solved the problem.
No toast text is showing at 10 seconds still :(

Comment: you can use handler to displaly toast in every 10 seconds.

Comment: How would I implement a handler into the code i posted? had a go and still not displaying anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the code below:

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, serviceIntent, 0);
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 10000, pi);
```

I didn't use a BroadcastReviver. I called a Service every 10 seconds.

**The new solution:**

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, serviceIntent, 0);
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 10000, pi);
```

MyActivity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             Toast.makeText(context, "HOUR NOTIFICATION", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
}
```

Comment: does this go in the main activity class, where does the code for the toast go?

Comment: I'm launching MyService.class every 10 seconds. You can define your own service or activity and set it when you declaring your pendingintent: Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, YourServiceOrActivity.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, serviceIntent, 0);

Comment: In your Service or Activity, you can put the code for the toast. You should create a Service or an Activity instead of a BroadcastReciver.

Comment: Thanks for this Alex.
I've placed the 2nd code snippet down into my main activity file and then ive changed the broadcast receiver file to the bottom code snippet. I'm getting the error for 'context' saying context cannot be resolved to a variable in both files though! Any ideas? :)